# Php pagination numbering

Tags: php, pagination

I have a Php pagination. I have 166 records and I'm trying to display the total number of records depends on page number.

```
$itemsPerPage = 60; //total records 166     
$i = $id2 * $itemsPerPage - $itemsPerPage + 1;
$k = $id2 * $itemsPerPage;
echo $i.'-'.$k;
```

The output of this code,

When page number is `echo $i.'-'.$k;`

Page 1 output is 1-60  //correct

Page 2 output is 61-120  //correct

Page 3 output should 121-180 //wrong

But the problem is in the last page I'm getting 121-180. How I can get the exact value of 121-166 output?

Comment: do you have a total records variable?

Comment: $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ASC");
$nr = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

Comment: To do pagination where you display either the total number of records and/or the total number of pages, you must have determined the total number of records available for display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple fix.

```
if($k > $nr){
$k=$nr;
}
```

Comment: can i stop you? :-) yes you can ask

Comment: :) just want to ask what the of {$prefix} in $sql = "delete from {$prefix}sub_list1 where id='$id'"; ?

Comment: at a guess that would be the db name. ie `$sql = "delete from MY_DB.sub_list1 where id='$id'"; ` you could have one db, you could have hundreds

Comment: Okay, I saw this in some tutorial but I can't figure out how's it function and why that code is inside of the query. Can I remove that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use function `min()`. For example:

```
$k = min($k, $nr);
```